# How to add image to Redmine Welcome text without webserver

Tags: markdown, redmine

I put the following to home page in Redmine 4.1 on RHEL 7, which is
using **Markdown** as Text formatting:

```
![grey](1280x40-grey.png)
```

I put this into Administration -> Settings -> General -> Welcome text

Now, where should I put file *1280x40-grey.png* to show it. Have been tried
to put it into files or upload as File or upload as attachment to one issue,
but no success.

I do not have web server, I have started Redmine as:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `public` folder serves as the web root of any Rails application. So if you put your image there, and change the Markdown to point to `/1280x40-grey.png`, it should work.

Another way, which works without direct access to the server's file system, would be to upload the image as an attachment somewhere in a public project (i.e. on a Wiki page) and use the download path of the attachment in your markdown (should look something like `/attachments/download/<id>/filename.png`).

Permissions apply, so be sure to attach it to an object that is accessible for anonymous users as well, otherwise the image will only be visible to signed in users with permission to see the object where you attached the image.